# Laravel 5.4 array remove key index

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller, this statement generates an array:

```
// sort the region collection by continent for faster access in front end
$finalRegions = $regions->sortBy('continent_id');


{  
   "0":{  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Alaska",
      "image_x":227,
      "image_y":117
   },
   "1":{  
      "id":5,
      "name":"Australian Antartic Territory",
      "image_x":1187,
      "image_y":1037
....
   }
}
```

How do I remove the index from the resulting object, so it looks like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Alaska",
      "image_x":227,
      "image_y":117
   },
   {  
      "id":5,
      "name":"Australian Antartic Territory",
      "image_x":1187,
      "image_y":1037
....
   }
]
```

This is stored in a field cast as `json` in the table class.

Comment: In my opinion, you can't because this is not a valid JSON

Comment: Hi @vietnguyen09 you are right! My typo. I have fixed the Q. I want an array of objects without the index

Comment: Why do you need to remove those indexes?

Comment: Consistency. I have three other fields which contain json array of objects. I then access them the same way in JS on front end. I also do not understand why this one field (which starts off as a collection like the other three) gets formatted this way at the end of the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$res = [];
foreach ($finalRegions  as $key => $value) {
    $res[] = $value;
}

// $res contains desired result
```

Edit: Simple one liner (thanks to Jannie)

```
$res = array_values($finalRegions)
```

Comment: long way of saying `array_values($finalRegions)` ?

Comment: Haha, I used PHP way back and didn't remember using this, so proposed an old school way. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have "Laravel" in your question title and it looks like you already have your regions in a Laravel Collection, there is an easier way. Just pipe your results through ->values() *after* the ->sortBy() clause like this:

```
$finalRegions = $regions->sortBy('continent_id')->values();
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't get why you need to remove those indexes, but you can do by this way.

```
<?php

$jsonArr = '{  
   "0":{  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Alaska",
      "image_x":227,
      "image_y":117
   },
   "1":{  
      "id":5,
      "name":"Australian Antartic Territory",
      "image_x":1187,
      "image_y":1037
   }
}';

$decodeArr = json_decode($jsonArr, true);
print_r(json_encode($decodeArr));
```

This is just my idea, and you can edit part of your code where the query returns your JSON string.